adding additional fill variable in ggplot2
I have the following data and code:
#data
Congruency <- c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC")
Event <- c("contact", "description", "dislocation", "manipulation", "oration", "perception", "contact", "description", "dislocation", "manipulation", "oration", "perception")
Speech_VP <- c("N", "N", "N", "N", "CH", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "CH", "N")
n <- c(5, 486, 97, 44, 228, 12, 23, 232, 34, 73, 130, 26)

#create dataframe
plot_df <- data.frame(Congruency, Event, Speech_VP, n)

#plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=plot_df, aes(x=Event, y=n, fill=Congruency, group = Speech_VP)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "stack") +labs(y= "Count", x = "Event Type") + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Congruence"))

Which produces the following plot:

I cannot figure out how to integrate additional fill, in this case, the 'Speech_VP' column in the data frame. I looked into the ggpattern package as per questions like this one, but the syntax is difficult and it doesn't quite fit my use case.
For this particular dataset, only the 'oration' column has the Speech_VP values of "CH". Is there some way I could make this column have slashes through it or a cross-hatch, and have a legend that shows that the effect is for CH, and the solid color is for N?

You could facet on Speech_VP, specifying "free" for scales and space:
ggplot(data=plot_df, aes(x=Event, y=n, 
       fill=Congruency, group = Speech_VP)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "stack") +
  labs(y= "Count", x = "Event Type") + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Congruence")) +
  facet_grid(~Speech_VP, 
              scales="free_x", space ="free", labeller=label_both) +
  theme_minimal()



How about using interaction()?
ggplot(data = plot_df, aes(x = Event, y = n, fill = interaction(Congruency, Speech_VP))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  labs(y = "Count", x = "Event Type") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Congruence"))


Or using ggpattern:
library(ggpattern)
ggplot(plot_df) +
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(
      x = Event,
      y = n, fill = Congruency, 
      pattern = Speech_VP), 
      pattern_density = 0.3
  ) +
  labs(y = "Count", x = "Event Type") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Congruence"))+
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, 'cm')) 



I do like your second solution with ggpattern, however I am unable to replicate completely, when I run your code on the same dataset, the legend for congruence adds the stripes to both of the colour blocks for C and NC
also, the legend for Speech VP looks different as well, the dark grey box for character shows black slashes through it, and the N block shows black dots, whereas yours has a single light grey dot

I have edited my answer. I added pattern_density = 0.3 and theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, 'cm')). You may want to adjust some parameters to get expected results.
